# Edit .aspx file in published project(Visual Studio)

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, publish

We have an CMS project, we will publish the project for deploying to PROD server,
However we found that if we changed  aspx file content in published project, e.g. Modify label control text,
an error will error.

[image]

Is there are any contraint for pubsliehd .aspx and .dll?
Can we just just modify aspx file without re-publish and deploy it again?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What kind of actions will trigger the error? Modifying text attribute in a label control shouldn't immediately throwing error. Note that once published as DLL, the code behind control design code is compiled, avoid adding new controls or removing existing ones in published ASPX page to keep control binding.

Comment: You can use quote to show us the error msg instead of screen shot.

Comment: If you need to directly access the content of server frequently. Then, you may wanna switch to website instead of web application.

Comment: hello Yamamoto. We just change the text of label control in aspx, then the error will occur.We did not change any .cs file

Comment: hello 蕭為元. Our CMS project is an WebSite Project

Comment: hello 蕭為元. We did not need to access the content of server frequently.We  just want to change the text of label control in aspx without re-publish and re deploy it again